# Signing Error during kernel compilation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel

I was trying to compile kernel on my system by following this link http://www.ramkitech.com/2012/04/how-to-compile-kernel-step-by-step.html

when I run **make** command, I am getting the following error

```
 writing new private key to 'signing_key.priv'
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
make[1]: *** [signing_key.x509] Error 132
make: *** [kernel] Error 2
```

Can you please help me to solve this error and build my kernel (linux-3.18.20).

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32bit (kernel 3.13.0-24-generic), downloaded kernel source from kernel.org (latest kernel linux-3.18.20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Your processor attempted to execute an instruction it doesn't recognize in OpenSSL. This may be an issue with your OpenSSL installation.

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

- Make sure OpenSSL isn't compiled for the wrong CPU architecture. It's possible that your copy of OpenSSL is compiled for a newer CPU and your CPU doesn't support certain newer instructions such as one of the [SSE instruction sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions).
- If this isn't the case, your OpenSSL installation may be corrupt and you may need to reinstall it.

Comment: There was issue with Openssl version. As per your suggestion I have reinstalled openssl and now I am able to compile my kernel. Thanks.